# Cross top Levers as primary brake

Tags: brakes, cyclocross, build, brake-levers

Has anyone ever tried to use Cross Top levers as your only braking method (ie not just as an interrupter for the drop levers)?

I'm guessing it wouldn't work as you need the cable to go straight through the lever but thought it might be possible to jerry rig a cable clamp / nipple of some sort

Thoughts

Comment: Maybe you could just use a mtn (flat bar) brake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of people do this, enough that at some points it's been a fashion on fixed gears. All you have to do is put the cable through the normal way with the head resting on the back side of the lever, where it will sit in the housing slot. There are some levers that are made to accommodate the cable head there snugly using a removable plastic bit.

The main reason to do it is if you want a flatbar style lever on a clamp diameter they're not otherwise available for, I.e. 23.8, 25.4, 26.0, and 31.8mm, and you either don't want to mess with forcing/adapting a standard 22.2 lever or there's no real way to do it, as in 31.8. If you can just use a 22.2 bmx lever, that's what I would tend to do, because they're generally better brake levers.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at the lever and I reckon an old style pear nipple would fit quite nicely!